# Rails relation overload

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, model

Let's say I have the following models:

```
Class Wishlist
    belongs_to :user # User class is irrelevant here
    has_many :inclusions
    has_many :products, :through => :inclusions
  end

  Class Product
    has_many :inclusions
    has_many :wishlists, :through => :inclusions
  end

  Class Inclusion
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :wishlist
  end
```

inclusions/index.html.erb

```
  <%= render @inclusions %>
```

inclusions/_inclusion.html.erb

```
  <%= "#{ inclusion.quantity } #{ inclusion.product.name } #{ inclusion.wishlist.user.name }"%>
```

This example is trivial, but the point is: the amount of database queries is overwhelming. For every instance of _inclusion.html.erb, at least three new queries seem to be created.
Is there a way to prefetch this information beforehand, maybe through a JOIN command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
 @inclusions = Inclusions.includes(:product, { :wishlist => :user })
```

Read about eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

have you thinking about creating sql view, called for example ProductsWishlist and (if the performance will be bad) materializing it?

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-views.html